# 120fps video playback issues

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, media-player-classic, 120hz

Unable to playback the 120FPS video downloaded from http://www.blurbusters.com/hfr-120fps-video-game-recording/

For VLC it moves at 20fps and is all pixelated (with lots of artefacts) and broken
In MPC-HC it moves smoothly at 60fps and everything is in slow motion
In DivX player (Latest) it starts playing but freezes at 3 sec
In ZoomPlayer it plays back at 70-78fps

How can I make it play the video at 120fps?

### Software:

KLite Codec Pack 10.6.0 (Latest)
VLC Media Player 2.1.3 (Latest)
ZoomPlayer (Latest)

### Hardware:

ATI Radeon HD4870 (Latest drivers)
BenQ XL2411Z (Version 1 firmware, 1920x1080@120Hz)
AMD 3GHz Dual Core

### Notes:

The monitor is connected through a Dual DVI cable (it has all the pins)
The graphics card has one DVI and one VGA output 
The monitor is currently working at 120Hz in the windows settings (there were no problems with this)
The monitor driver is installed from the CD
http://www.testufo.com/#test=framerates does not display 120Hz. Only 60Hz, 30Hz and less

If you need more info please ask.

Comment: To narrow the problem down (and just for the fun of it). Try to play the video on the same hardware running a different system, for example live distro of linux - and let us know the results

Comment: I have tried the example video on a fast computer with a high-level NVIDIA card. The results are very good and almost identical with either Windows Media Player, VLC or MPC-HC. I think that your computer specs are not up to playing such enormous videos at that speed, and this can be either because of the video card, memory, the bus, the disk, or even all of them.

Comment: @harrymc does this still apply if I downloaded the low resolution version? (I never tried the full resolution one)

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the example video on a fast computer with a high-level NVIDIA card.

I have downloaded both MP4 versions : "High Quality (fast GPU)" and
"Low Quality (slower GPU)". I use the K-Lite Mega Codec Pack.

Playing the High Quality version, the results were very good and almost identical with either Windows Media Player, VLC or MPC-HC.

However, playing the Low Quality version was impossible with Windows Media Player
because of high pixelation and stuck video. The results were however good with VLC and MPC-HC.

I hazard two conclusions :

1. The Low Quality version is badly encoded in such a way that makes its playing
   impossible, at least with Windows Media Player (which uses K-Lite, while the others
   use mostly codecs that come packaged with them).
2. Your computer specs may not be up to playing such videos at that speed, and this can be either because of the video card, memory, the bus, the disk, or even all of them.

In the second case, using a good video converter may convert the videos to something
you can watch.

Try and see how you can play the High Quality version (life is full of surprises).

Comment: I tried the high quality version and it's playback is identical to the low quality version in MPC-HC and ZoomPlayer, in VLC and Windows Media Player it actually plays better but still slow motion and the video did not get stuck at any point.

Comment: What would be the symptoms that it is the fault of a slow rig? Shouldn't it be pixelated and broken or should it just playback slower that it should? I am worried that it is some kind of driver/firmware limitation on the framerate. (thank you for helping)

Comment: You could try and see if ATI offers a better driver than Windows in the [ATI Download Center](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download). There is not much else that you can do on the software side. A comment above mentioned running a live Linux CD and comparing the Windows results with these totally different drivers. Otherwise, trying your videos on another and more recent desktop could also be informative.